# Valid checkbox is checked in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

Happy Tuesday!
What is the best approach to valid that checkbox is check before submitting the form in PowerApps.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can either set required value of the field to true and check Form1.Valid or if in this case (case where fields are very less),you can directly check the value of the field like **chkMember.Value = true || chkPatient.Value =true** and you can patch the data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make both required field true on SharePoint List and PowerApp
and use

```
If(!Form1.Valid,SubmitForm(Form1),Patch(Test,Defaults(Test),Form1.Updates)
```